# How can I join denormalized tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with different `people`. And I want to connect them to my `house` table

`house` table:

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| house | person1 | person2 | person3 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|     1 |       2 |       4 |       1 |
|     2 |       3 |       1 |       2 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

`people` table:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | fred |
|  2 | john |
|  3 | leo  |
|  4 | tom  |
+----+------+
```

Is something like this possible?

```
$pdo = $db->query('
 SELECT *
 FROM house
 LEFT JOIN people
 ON house.person1=people.id
 AND house.person2=people.id
 ;');
 while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Person 1 = ".$row['name'];
    echo "Person 2 = ".$row['name'];
 }
```

Comment: Please change your `house` table to have **one person per row** not _one person per column_. i.e. one row:  `house_id int, person_id int`. That way, you can add new people to a house. Use the group functions to count people per house etc. Joins are easier to match people to houses.

Comment: You should normalise your house table, otherwise you need join to the persons table 3 times.

Comment: Try to use `OR` instead of `AND`. like `house.person1=people.id
 OR house.person2=people.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, you need `OR` or `IN()` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT *
FROM house h
LEFT JOIN people p ON p.id IN(h.person1,h.person2,h.person3)
```

But I believe, a better approach is to change your table design as proposed by the comments. In that case you will simply need:

```
SELECT *
FROM house h
LEFT JOIN people p ON h.person = p.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use self join  on table people 3 name with 3 alias

```
  $pdo = $db->query('
   SELECT *, people1.name  as name1, people2.name  as name2, people3.name  as name3
   FROM house
   LEFT JOIN people as people1 ON house.person1=people1.id
   LEFT JOIN people as people2 ON house.person2=people2.id
   LEFT JOIN people as people3 ON house.person3=people3.id
   ;');
   while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "Person 1 = ".$row['name1'];
      echo "Person 2 = ".$row['name2'];
      echo "Person 3 = ".$row['name3'];
   }
```

Comment: @RyanVincent   many thanks for suggestion  ...missing correct tables  alias  .. answer  updated ..

Comment: @Jarla This is the **wrong** approach. See comments under your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to know the name of the 3 person in every house, you can use this

```
$pdo = $db->query('
select A.house, B.name as person1, C.name as person2, D.name as person3
from house A join people B on (A.person1=B.id) left join people C on   (A.person2=C.id) join people D on (A.person3=D.id)
;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "house = ".$row['house']; 
  echo "Person 1 = ".$row['person1'];
  echo "Person 2 = ".$row['person2'];
  echo "Person 2 = ".$row['person3'];
}
```